# MySQL display severals row content with one rows user?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to select a user (user 2 for example), and have him display the contents of all the users which field has the string "happy" included.

Table has two fields, id and content. So the table would like as so.

```
id     content
1      happy days
2      sad days
3      not very happy
etc...
```

I would like the result to be in somewhat

```
2     not very happy happy days etc.
```

Is this possible? I've tried the following:

```
select * 
from table 
where id = 2 
    or join table.content on table.content LIKE 'happy%'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want `group_concat()`:

```
select group_concat(t.content separator ' ')
from table t
where t.id = or t.content like 'happy%'
```

If the values can be on separate lines, then you just need the `where` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Gordon Linoff answer is correct just add distinct :

```
select id,group_concat( distinct content separator ' ')
from table 
where id = 2 
    or  table.content LIKE 'happy%'
```